# User's possibilities on site

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I want to build a system on the website, that allows users to do some things depend on their rating. For example I have rule for rating value X:

- 1 post in 3 days
- 10 comments in 1 day
- 20 votes in 2 days

for rating value Y, rule may be following:

- 3 post in 1 day
- 50 comments in 1 day
- 30 votes in 1 day

Each night I recalculate users' ratings, so I know what each user is able to do.
Possibilities don't sum or reset on each rating's recalculation.

One more important thing is that admin can fill concrete user's possibilities at any time.

What is optimal database (MySQL) structure for desired?

I can count what concrete user has done:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE UserID=XXX AND DateOfPost >= 'YYY'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE UserID=XXX AND CommentOfPost >= 'YYY'
```

But how can I do admin filling possibilities in this case?

Comment: +1 - nice question. Sorry I can't actually _help_ you on it ;-P

Comment: What does "admin can fill concrete user's responsibilities" mean?

Comment: It means, that if user already used some own possibilities (for example, posts blogpost and 5 comments) and his full possibilities are "POSTS: 1, COMMENTS: 10", admin can make, that this user has again full possibilities "POSTS: 1, COMMENTS: 10".

Comment: and this possibilities will be given constantly or as any other they will be recalculated in the midnight? If not - then what if user will collect points (or whatever they collect at your site) and should get **bigger** possibilities - should the ones specified by admin be rewritten then?

Comment: Not constantly. Possibilities depend on users' rating. Rating is recalculated each night. Each night I have knowledge, what possibilities each user have. Next night possibilities can be different (smaller/bigger). Admin can fill full user's possibilities for this knowlegde. Sorry for my English :) If user already used some of own possibilites, admin can do at any time (can do many times per day, hour...), that user have again full possibilites (he received the previous night)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would log the number of actions of each user each day and use that table to compare.

This table would contain the following fields:

- **date**: the day when the action took place
- **count**: the number of actions took that day
- **userId**: who did this action
- **action**: which action post/comment/vote/...
- **ignore**: boolean, if this is set, admin has reset the values

Checking a rule: *SELECT SUM(count) FROM log WHERE userId = XXX AND action = YYY AND ignore = 0 AND DATEDIFF(date, NOW()) <= DAYS*

Resetting a rule: *UPDATE ignore = 1 FROM log WHERE userId = XXX*

If his rating changes the result is still valid (you'll just compare with on other total)

When you create a rules table:

- **action**
- **limits**
- **days**
- **rating_min**
- **rating_max**

You can query for permissions like this:

```
SELECT action, IF(SUM(count) < MIN(limits), 1, 0) as can_do_action FROM log LEFT JOIN rules ON rules.action = log.action WHERE userId = XXX AND rating_min <= RATING AND rating_max >= RATING AND ignore = 0 AND DATEDIFF(date, NOW()) <= days
```

So you get a table loggin like this:
  - comment => 1
  - votes => 0

You do have to update this table every action (create a new row if first action of the day or update the count of the row)

The absence of a rule means no actions have been made, so we can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks! Using ignore field is very nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

What about having, in the user table, three columns called `remainingPosts`, `remainingComments` and `remainingVotes`? You'll decrease the columns when the user has performed a specific action, and in this way the admin can always "refill" those columns, even above the original limit.

===

Another option is to store the expiration of the permissions in those columns, so that you can reset the permissions just putting the expiry for a certain column to the day before. You can then use your queries to get the remaining number of posts/comments/votes for the user.

Comment: This is the simplest solution. But if I have rule for example "3 posts in 3 days", how do I know when and how I need to 'refill' these counters again, if user used only part of them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have a user that can post 1 blog, and comment 10 times. Now he/she has commented 5 times and posted a blog. You want the admin to click a button, and now the user can again post a blog and comment 10 times?

It might be a bit of a hack, but you could count the actions that are being reset/ignored, and substract that from the current actions?

e.g.: user has 1 blog and 5 comments. Admin presses "reset", and you save those values.
Now as the user posts another blog, and you check if that's allowed, you'll get

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE UserID=XXX AND DateOfPost >= 'YYY'
```

And you do something like this

```
SELECT changes FROM adminTable WHERE UserID=XXX AND  type = 'post'
```

And if count - changes is ok, you're set.

Comment: Seems to be ok, but can you explain deeper, please. What is in adminTable and how and when data will be inserted/updated/deleted in this table? What happens next day or admin pressed again 'reset' button? I didn't get this idea in details, but from afar it seems to be cool solution.

Comment: Well, 'admintable' is just a random name for a table that would save the values you want to 'substract' from the totals. They are updated when the admin presses the "reset" button, and emptied every night.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest separating the two concerns entirely:

- The process of enabling features/possibilities to users
- The data model of user features

For example, you could have a simple many-to-many table representing user features:

```
user_features(
   user_id
  ,feature_id
  ,source      (admin|earned)
  ,primary key(user_id, feature_id)
);
```

This makes it really easy for an administrator to disable/enable parts or all of the feature set.

Your nightly job would query relevant tables and grant/revoke features by inserting/deleting from this table.

If you go with this approach, you can actually give the features either based on a rating or specific actions.

A rule such as "3 posts in 3 days", can be implemented like this:

```
when a user posts, check if the previous post was made within 24 hours.
if yes then
   increment counter by 1
   record current timestamp

   if counter = 3 then
      grant feature to user
else 
   reset counter to 1 
   record current timestamp
```

You would need two columns (post_count:int, last_post:date) in some table keyed by user_id.